# Convert XML file to Magento Order with VB Visual Basic with multiple products. SOAP

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, vb.net

I have the code to convert a order from XML file to Magento 1.7 order. But only works with one product if I load some product I get an error when I assign the payment method.

ERROR: 
Additional information: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sales_flat_quote_item_option`, CONSTRAINT `FK_B001F37CDAA20BF32FE60F8EC5ACAE0B` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `mg_sales_flat_quote_item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE C)

CODE:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CrearPedido()


    End Sub

    Private Function CrearPedido()
        'Dim booksFromFile As XElement = XElement.Load("000071-07092015122243.xml")
        'Console.WriteLine(booksFromFile)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.InferXmlSchema(("000071-07092015122243.xml"), Nothing)
        ds.ReadXml("000071-07092015122243.xml")

        Dim CodigoC As String
        Dim Observaciones As String
        Dim Promo As String
        CodigoC = ds.Tables(1).Rows(0).Item("Codigo")
        Observaciones = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Observaciones")
        Promo = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Promo")

        Dim CustomerID = GetCustomerID(CodigoC)
        Dim AddressID = GetCliente(CustomerID)

        Dim CM As New MagentoService.MagentoService
        Dim sesionID = CM.login("apiuser", "frfwer764fjfwe43_")

        Dim customer = New MagentoService.shoppingCartCustomerEntity
        customer.mode = "customer"
        customer.customer_id = CustomerID
        customer.customer_idSpecified = True

        Dim address(0) As MagentoService.shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntity
        address(0) = New MagentoService.shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntity
        address(0).mode = "shipping"
        address(0).address_id = AddressID '3
        address(0).is_default_shipping = 1
        address(0).is_default_billing = 1
        address(0).is_default_billingSpecified = 1
        address(0).is_default_shippingSpecified = 1

        Dim address2(0) As MagentoService.shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntity
        address2(0) = New MagentoService.shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntity
        address2(0).mode = "billing"
        address2(0).address_id = AddressID '3
        address2(0).is_default_shipping = 1
        address2(0).is_default_billing = 1
        address2(0).is_default_billingSpecified = 1
        address2(0).is_default_shippingSpecified = 1


        Dim pago = New MagentoService.shoppingCartPaymentMethodEntity
        pago.method = "banktransfer"

        Dim licenses(0) As String
        licenses(0) = ""

        Dim carritoID = CM.shoppingCartCreate(sesionID, "1")
        CM.shoppingCartCustomerSet(sesionID, carritoID, customer, "1")
        Dim info2 = CM.shoppingCartCustomerAddresses(sesionID, carritoID, address, "1")
        Dim info3 = CM.shoppingCartCustomerAddresses(sesionID, carritoID, address2, "1")

        ''WORKS WITH ONLY ONE PRODUCT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        'Dim producto(0) As MagentoService.shoppingCartProductEntity
        'producto(0) = New MagentoService.shoppingCartProductEntity
        'producto(0).sku = "LLDEST"
        ''producto(0).product_id = "141723"
        'producto(0).qty = "1"
        'CM.shoppingCartProductAdd(sesionID, carritoID, producto, "1")

        'FAILS WITH MORE THAN ONE PRODUCT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        'Dim producto(ds.Tables(3).Rows.Count - 1) As MagentoService.shoppingCartProductEntity
        'For i = 0 To ds.Tables(3).Rows.Count - 1
        'producto(i) = New MagentoService.shoppingCartProductEntity
        'producto(i).sku = ds.Tables(3).Rows(i).Item("Sku")
        'producto(i).product_id = ds.Tables(3).Rows(i).Item("Id")
        'producto(i).qty = ds.Tables(3).Rows(i).Item("Qty")
        'Next
        'CM.shoppingCartProductAdd(sesionID, carritoID, producto, "1")

        'Dim producto(0) As MagentoService.shoppingCartProductEntity
        'producto(0) = New MagentoService.shoppingCartProductEntity
        'producto(0).sku = ds.Tables(3).Rows(0).Item("Sku")
        'producto(0).product_id = ds.Tables(3).Rows(0).Item("Id")
        'producto(0).qty = ds.Tables(3).Rows(0).Item("Qty")
        'CM.shoppingCartProductAdd(sesionID, carritoID, producto, "1")

        Dim pendingCartItems As New List(Of MagentoService.shoppingCartProductEntity)
        Dim ticketRequest As New MagentoService.shoppingCartProductEntity
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(3).Rows.Count - 1
            ticketRequest.sku = ds.Tables(3).Rows(0).Item("Sku")
            'ticketRequest.product_id = ds.Tables(3).Rows(0).Item("Id")
            ticketRequest.qty = ds.Tables(3).Rows(0).Item("Qty")
            pendingCartItems.Add(ticketRequest)
        Next
        CM.shoppingCartProductAdd(sesionID, carritoID, pendingCartItems.ToArray(), "1")

        CM.shoppingCartShippingMethod(sesionID, carritoID, "flatrate_flatrate", "1")

        'FAIL IN NEXT ROW WITH MULTIPLE PRODUCTS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        CM.shoppingCartPaymentMethod(sesionID, carritoID, pago, "1")
        CM.shoppingCartTotals(sesionID, carritoID, "1")
        'Dim info = CM.shoppingCartInfo(sesionID, carritoID, "1")
        CM.shoppingCartOrder(sesionID, carritoID, "1", licenses)

    End Function


    Private Function GetCliente(CustomerID)
        Dim pws As New MagentoService.MagentoService
        Dim sesionID = pws.login("apiuser", "frfwer7jfwe43_")
        Dim result
        result = pws.customerAddressList(sesionID, CustomerID)
        Return (result(0).customer_address_id)
    End Function

    Private Function GetCustomerID(CodigoC)
        Dim pws As New MagentoService.MagentoService
        Dim sesionID = pws.login("apiuser", "frfwwe43_")
        Dim result

        Dim filters As New MagentoService.filters
        Dim complexFilter(0) As MagentoService.complexFilter
        complexFilter(0) = New MagentoService.complexFilter
        complexFilter(0).key = "codigo_c"
        Dim assEnt As New MagentoService.associativeEntity
        With assEnt
            .key = "eq"
            .value = CodigoC
        End With
        complexFilter(0).value = assEnt

        filters.complex_filter = complexFilter

        result = pws.customerCustomerList(sesionID, filters)
        'result = pws.customerAddressList(sesionID, 6)

        Return (result(0).customer_id)
    End Function


End Class
```

Any idea? Thanks and enjoy the code!